# How to convert shape file x, y coordinate to lat long in php

Tags: php, yii2, latitude-longitude, shapefile

Hello I am working with shape file in my yii2 project. I have created function to upload and read shape files. (.shp, .shx, .dbf).

I am getting data like :

[image]

In above image I am getting x and y cordinate. From it how can i get lat and long ?

I need to save this in database and display in map.

How to convert x and y to lat and long in php.

Comment: x and y are lat and lng  .. what do you mean .? . you need  a specific conversion ? .. which conversion  do you need .. ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` coordinates are the latitudes and `y` coordinates are the longitudes. There is no need to convert these unless you want to work with a coordinate system that doesn't use decimal degrees.